# Context.Item value is coming as null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, null

On a page we have submit button, on clicking it we are getting error due to m_strPageDefinition has null value. Following is the code of it for more insight. Only sometimes and only in production we are getting value of `m_strPageDefinition` as `null`, which is causing problems. Does anyone has idea why `m_strPageDefinition` is coming `null`.

```
Private m_strPageDefinition As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

       If Not IsPostBack  Then
            If (Not Context.Items("MyXmlString") = Nothing) And (Not Context.Items("mFormID") = Nothing) Then
                MyXMLString = Context.Items("MyXmlString")
                MyHiddenXMLString.Value = MyXMLString
            End If
        Else
            m_strPageDefinition = MyHiddenXMLString.Value
        End If

End Sub

Private Property MyXMLString()
        Get
            Return m_strPageDefinition
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            m_strPageDefinition = value
        End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Where are you setting `Context.Items("MyXmlString")`?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider being more consistent how you address m_strPageDefinition.  Why are you accessing is a private variable instead of always using the Property setter?  e.g.

```
Private m_strPageDefinition As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


If Not IsPostBack  Then
    If (Not Context.Items("MyXmlString") = Nothing) And (Not Context.Items("mFormID") = Nothing) Then
        MyXMLString = Context.Items("MyXmlString")
        MyHiddenXMLString.Value = MyXMLString
    Else
        MyXMLString = MyHiddenXMLString.Value
    End If
Else
    MyXMLString = MyHiddenXMLString.Value
End If

End Sub

Private Property MyXMLString() 
    Get 
        Return m_strPageDefinition 
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value)         
        m_strPageDefinition = value 
    End Set 
End Property
```

I believe your issue is coming from the missing "Else" I have included here in the Not IsPostBack statement.  Forgive me for VB.NET is not a language I code in, so the format/structure might be off a bit.

Comment: The solution you suggested will not work as on first page_load() (and its not post back) MyHiddenXMLString.Value has null/empty value.         
Let me elaborate this problem bit more.  When user enters some data on page and clicks on Submit button, value from hidden variable is taken and used. The problem comes when hidden variable has no value.  Then the only question comes why hidden variable has no value. The only probable reason found is Context.Items("MyXmlString") sometimes somehow has null value on production. I never managed to reproduce thie error :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
m_strPageDefinition = MyHiddenXMLString.Value
```

and more specifically: `MyHiddenXMLString.Value` is probably null.

I couldn't figure out where you declared MyHiddenXMLString, but how about making it a hidden variable (input type="hidden" .. ) on the aspx side and setting it's value when the page loads the first time.

Then you know the value will always be there and easy to access.

hth

Comment: MyHiddenXMLString is already a hidden variable (input type="hidden" .. ). Somehow value is not saved in it during first page load, may be because Context.Items("MyXmlString") has null value.

Comment: allright, think I'm with you.. Now, the only way that m_strPageDefinition would be null and not "" is if it never got set in the first place (since calling .Value on a hidden variable returns a string)

Comment: Therefore, if m_strPageDefinition is null (and not "") that means:

if we're looking at the code inside Page_Load's Else: 

m_strPageDefinition = MyHiddenXMLString.Value. 

Then m_strPageDefinition must be at least "" unless we're trying to retrieve m_strPageDefinition before Page_Load kicks off on the postback.

Is there any other place on the page's code where we're trying to retrieve either m_strPageDefinition or MyXMLString?